# Average and Median in one query in Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, average, median

I have the following data in my table:

```
SELECT category, value FROM test
```

```
 
| category | value |
+----------+-------+
|    1     |   1   | 
|    1     |   3   |
|    1     |   4   |
|    1     |   8   |
```

Right now I am using two separate queries.

1. To get average:

   ```
     SELECT category, avg(value) as Average
       FROM test
   GROUP BY category
   ```

   ```
    
    | category | value |
    +----------+-------+
    |    1     |   4   |
   ```
2. To get median:

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT category, 
                   PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) 
                      WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) 
                      OVER (partition BY category) AS Median
              FROM test
   ```

   ```
    
    | category | value |
    +----------+-------+
    |    1     |  3.5  |
   ```

Is there any way to merge them in one query?

Note: I know that I can also get median with two subqueries, but I prefer to use PERCENTILE_CONT function to get it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

AVG is also a windowed function:

```
select 
distinct
category,
avg(value) over (partition by category) as average,
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) 
                   WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) 
                   OVER (partition BY category) AS Median
                   from test
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this in a slightly different way:

```
select category, avg(value) as avg,
       avg(case when 2 * seqnum in (cnt, cnt + 1, cnt + 2) then value end) as median
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by category order by value) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by category) as cnt
      from test t
     ) t
group by category;
```

Comment: still have to GROUP BY category at the end for the AVG function.

Comment: It looks more complicated that previous answer... Does this approach has a better performance?

Comment: It returns the wrong answer, too (3 for the data set above instead of 3.5)

Comment: If you change cnt -1, cnt, cnt+ 1 to cnt, cnt+1, cnt + 2 it works correctly.

Comment: @KyleHale . . . I believe you are right on both counts.  My preference for this approach is a distaste of mixing `select distinct` with window/analytic functions.  I find the logic of such queries hard to follow.  As for performance, that needs to be tested on your data in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a more thorough answer to this question, and after some digging found it in this exhaustive analysis of multiple methods from Dwain Camps, in case others find it useful:

[Calculating the Median Value within a Partitioned Set Using T-SQL](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/calculating-the-median-value-within-a-partitioned-set-using-t-sql/)

I went with "his" 4th solution (he is combining/testing others' approaches), which was straightforward to understand and indeed performs well:

```
WITH Counts AS
(
   SELECT ID, c=COUNT(*)
   FROM #MedianValues
   GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT a.ID, Median=AVG(0.+N)
FROM Counts a
CROSS APPLY
(
   SELECT TOP(((a.c - 1) / 2) + (1 + (1 - a.c % 2)))
      N, r=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N)
   FROM #MedianValues b
   WHERE a.ID = b.ID
   ORDER BY N
) p
WHERE r BETWEEN ((a.c - 1) / 2) + 1 AND (((a.c - 1) / 2) + (1 + (1 - a.c % 2)))
GROUP BY a.ID;
```